# Action not triggered in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to redux and trying to fetch content from my BackEnd API. For some reason the action I call does not reach the reducer (It's not even executed). I first thought it was because it couldn't access the store since it is has a parent component but my Provider is well configured and there is another component at the same level, and just after i started thinking it was a problem with my dispatch but honestly i don't know. I have attached the code I feel is relevant and any contributions would be highly appreciated.

**actions/viewers.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { VIEWERS_LOADED, VIEWERS_ERROR } from './types';

export const loadData = async (body, http) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      http,
      body,
      config
    );
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const extractConcurrentViewers = (from, to, aggregate) => async dispatch => {
  console.log("CONCURRENT VIEWERS");
  const body = {
    session_token: localStorage.token,
    from,
    to,
  };

  try {
    let aggregateConcur = null;
    const graphConccur = await loadData(body, 'http://localhost:5000/audience');
    console.log('extractViews -> res_1', graphConccur);

    if (aggregate !== null) {
        body.aggregate = aggregate
        aggregateConcur = await loadData(body, 'http://localhost:5000/audience');
    }
    console.log('extractaggregateViewers -> res_2', aggregateConcur);

    dispatch({
      type: VIEWERS_LOADED,
      payload: {
        graphConccur,
        aggregateConcur
      },
    }); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({
      type: VIEWERS_ERROR,
    });
  }
}
```

**reducers/viewers.js**

```
import {
    VIEWERS_LOADED,
    VIEWERS_ERROR,
  } from '../actions/types';

  const initialState = {
    session_token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    concurrence: null,
    aggConcurrence: null,
  };

  export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
      case VIEWERS_LOADED:
        return {
          ...state,
          ...payload,
          concurrence: payload.graphConccur.audience,
          aggConcurrence: payload.aggregateConcur.audience,
        };
      case VIEWERS_ERROR:
        return {
          ...state,
          concurrence: null,
          aggConcurrence: null,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

**reducer/index.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import alert from './alert';
import auth from './auth'
import profile from './profile'
import chart from './chart'
import viewers from './viewers'


export default combineReducers({
    alert,
    auth,
    profile,
    chart,
    viewers
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRouting';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { loadUser } from './actions/auth';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken'
import './App.css';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser())
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
        <section className='container'>
          <Alert />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </section>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is where the function `extractConcurrentViewers` is to be called and the component supposed to use that is `<Concurrent concurrence={concurrence}/>` and what is really weird about is that the component just above it is implemented almost the same way but it's working.

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import BandWidth from './BandWidth';
import Concurrent from './Concurrent';
import { extractCurrentClient } from '../../actions/profile';
import { extractchartData } from '../../actions/chart';
import { extractConcurrentViewers } from '../../actions/viewers';

const Dashboard = ({
  extractCurrentClient,
  extractchartData,
  auth: { user },
  profile: { profile, loading },
  chart: { cdn, p2p, maxSum, maxCdn },
  viewers: {concurrence}
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    extractCurrentClient();
    extractchartData('max', 1585834831000, 1589118031000);
    extractConcurrentViewers(1585834831000, 1589118031000);
  }, []);
  return loading && profile === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Streaming</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-chart-line'></i>
        Welcome {user && user.lname}
      </p>
      <BandWidth cdn={cdn} p2p={p2p} maxSum={maxSum} maxCdn={maxCdn} />
      {/* <Concurrent concurrence={concurrence}/> */}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  extractCurrentClient: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  extractchartData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  extractConcurrentViewers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  profile: state.profile,
  chart: state.chart,
  viewers: state.viewers,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  extractCurrentClient,
  extractchartData,
  extractConcurrentViewers
})(Dashboard);
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: I see you are using hooks. Why you are not using hooks like useDispatch, useSelector? Try using useDispatch hook to fire actions. and where is loadUser action? I don't see it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mapped `extractConcurrentViewers` to props in `connect` but did not add it to the destructured props object. Since they share the same name, that means is you're calling your action creator without it being bound to `dispatch`, so it will not be delivered to your reducers.

```js
const Dashboard = ({
  extractCurrentClient,
  extractchartData,
  auth: { user },
  profile: { profile, loading },
  chart: { cdn, p2p, maxSum, maxCdn },
  viewers: {concurrence},
  extractConcurrentViewers // <-- add this
}) => {
```

Personally I don't destructure my `props` and this is one reason. I prefer the code to be explicit about where values and functions are coming from `props.extractConcurrentViewers` . But that's my preference.